# How to get the minimum of nested lists in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

See the following data frame for example,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([[[1, 2, 3, 4]],[[0, 2, 4]],[[]],[[3]]])
df.show()
```

Then we have

```
+------------+
|          _1|
+------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|   [0, 2, 4]|
|          []|
|         [3]|
+------------+
```

Then I want to find the minimum of each list; use -1 in case of empty list. I tried the following, which does not work.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
sim_col = F.col('_1')
df.withColumn('min_turn_sim', F.when(F.size(sim_col)==0, -1.0).otherwise(F.min(sim_col))).show()
```

The error is:

> AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (`_1` IS NULL) THEN -1.0D ELSE min(`_1`) END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;\n'Aggregate [_1#404, CASE WHEN isnull(_1#404) THEN -1.0 ELSE min(_1#404) END AS min_turn_sim#411]\n+- LogicalRDD [_1#404], false\n"

---

The size function will work. Don't understand why 'min' does not.

```
df.withColumn('min_turn_sim', F.when(F.size(sim_col)==0, -1.0).otherwise(F.size(sim_col))).show()

+------------+------------+
|          _1|min_turn_sim|
+------------+------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|         4.0|
|   [0, 2, 4]|         3.0|
|          []|        -1.0|
|         [3]|         1.0|
+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`min` is an aggregate function - it operates on columns, not values. Therefore `min(sim_col)` means minimum array value across all rows in the scoper, according to array ordering, not minimum value in each row.

To find a minimum for each row you'll need a non-aggregate function. In the latest Spark versions (2.4.0 and later) this would be `array_min` (similarly `array_max` to get the maximum value):

```py
df.withColumn("min_turn_sim", F.coalesce(F.array_min(sim_col), F.lit(-1)))
```

Earlier versions will require an UDF:

```py
@F.udf("long")
def long_array_min(xs):
    return min(xs) if xs else -1

df.withColumn("min_turn_sim", F.coalesce(long_array_min(sim_col), F.lit(-1))
```